# Switch between Custom theme variants (Light, Standard, Dark) using System Settings

Tags: gnome, themes, system-settings, 21.04

Is there a way to set which theme is applied by the Settings app, on the Appearance tab, in Ubuntu 21.04?

(Please note, I am not asking about changing themes using Gnome Tweaks or `gsettings`).

I have created a custom theme based on Yaru. My theme has Light, Standard, and Dark variants, just like Yaru.

However, when I switch theme variants in the Settings app, the corresponding official Yaru theme is selected.

*Are the three Yaru variants hard-coded in Settings,  or can this be configured?
If this can be configured, how/where is the configuration?*

In the example below, I would like...

- the "Light" button to activate my "Ubuntu-Blue-light" theme
- the "Standard" button to activate my "Ubuntu-Blue" theme
- the "Dark" button to activate my "Ubuntu-Blue-dark" theme

[image]